# Call static method with class name stored as instance variable

Tags: php

Consider this script

```
class B
{
    static public function hi() { echo "hi\n"; }
}
class A
{
    private $name = 'B';

    public function __construct()
    {
        // This doesn't parse
        // $this->name::hi();

        // But this works fine
        $class = $this->name;
        $class::hi();
    }
}
new A();
```

Any idea how/if I could get the first example `$this->name::hi();` to parse and work?

Comment: What version of PHP do you have? `$class::hi()` should work in 5.3.

Comment: he is saying // But this works fine  is working fine whats not working is the other one i think its not clear

Comment: @Barmar yes, he already said that, what does not work is `$this->$name::hi()`, looks like it should be `$this->name`, that's probably the problem.

Comment: i think its becos $name is just variables  you havent assigned the class B to that var yet..

Comment: If it worked, the syntax would be `$this->name::hi()`; you don't put a `$` after `->`. But it doesn't work. Apparently it only allows simple variables before `::`, not expressions.

Comment: Is it really so bad to have to create a variable first? Why do people need to turn everything into one-liners?

Comment: I think that kind of dynamic syntax is simply not supported by PHP parser, that's all. You need to use the second code (I would not even use it, in almost other languages, we don't even have such a feature and we're ***still happy***).

Comment: I've tried versions 5.5.9 and 5.6.0. I hear you about one liners, but in this case I'd argue it feels clunky to create a local variable first. Oh, and good catch on the typo I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation of Zend PHP parser supports only static method calls that are made directly on a class name or a variable. Here is the grammar:

```
%token T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM ":: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)"

function_call:
    name argument_list
        { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_CALL, $1, $2); }
|   class_name T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM member_name argument_list
        { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_STATIC_CALL, $1, $3, $4); }
|   variable_class_name T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM member_name argument_list
        { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_STATIC_CALL, $1, $3, $4); }
|   callable_expr argument_list
        { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_CALL, $1, $2); }
```

Source: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L890

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Given that in your current circumstances you require a method of the class b within the class a, it seems pretty anti intuitive to approach it this way. Further, the the availability to call a method of another class is simply not there, you would need to use:

```
call_user_func(array($this->name, 'hi'));
```

one way is to simply require the B class as a depency of the constructor function of the A class:

```
class B
{
    static public function hi() { echo "hi\n"; }
}

class A
{
    private $b;

    public function __construct(B $b)
    {

        $b::hi();

    }
}
new A(new B);
```

This is probably as close to the one liner approach that you're looking for that you can get.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, and actually changes the semantics anyway b/c I don't have an *instance* of B, I just want to refer to the *class* B, specifically through a string stored in an instance variable of another class.